# How do I get industry experience if I don't have industry experience?

Tags: job-search, new-job, software-development

Somehow I can't comment on my post (maybe my score is not high enough) so I'm going to edit my original question.

A lot mid-level and senior type roles require industry experience. If I can't get this experience at my job, how can I get industry experience?

In particular, I'm interested in getting a software developer role that uses certain libraries I don't have experience with, and can't get at my job. Projects on github are fine, but that doesn't get me industry experience. I've heard of doing free work for charities, but I'm not sure how to go about that.

Comment: What exactly does that mean? Is your job in the wrong field? Is it academia instead of industry? or do you think you learn nothing useful while doing your job?

Comment: "Fake it 'til you make it", which in this case is slightly less fraudulent. Apply for small companies and convince them you have what it takes. Then after working there for a while, you do have the real experience.

Answer (score 2):

You promote into it.

You're thinking you can interview from a non-midlevel job into one, but from an employer perspective, that doesn't happen.

Their thinking is, if you can't get to midlevel position at a place where you have been working already, why would you be able to do that at a completely new company?

The other case is if you got some type of degree or management specialization they want.  However, those with experience will usuals be top picks over those that are academic only.